# How do I display only match keyword in array

Tags: php

This is my array output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tweet_text] => Fedora 16 "Verne" released! http://t.co/lECbdzE0 #Fedora #Linux
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tweet_text] => Ubuntu 11.10 "Oneiric Ocelot" released! #Ubuntu #Linux
        )

)
```

Example to find `Ubuntu` keyword. From the current array how do I filter to show only

```
Array ( [1] => Array (
            [tweet_text] => Ubuntu 11.10 "Oneiric Ocelot" released! #Ubuntu #Linux
        )   
)
```

The code

```
$keywords = array('Ubuntu');

foreach ($keywords as &$keyword) {
    $keyword = preg_quote($keyword);
}

$regex = "/(" . implode('|', $keywords) . ")/";
$check = preg_match($regex, $anArray);

if($check == 1)  {
 // here I want to display only Ubuntu
}
```

Let me know

Comment: what's against [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[preg_grep](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) — Return array entries that match the pattern

example:-

```
$arr = array('k'=>'ubuntu', 'j'=>'ubuntu1', 'n'=>'fedorra');
$matches = preg_grep('/ubuntu/i', $arr);
```

if you original source is an multi-dimensional array,
you can try :-

```
 $cmp = array();
 foreach ($src as $key=>$arr)
 {
   $cmp[$key] = $arr['tweet_text'];
 }
 $matches = preg_grep('/ubuntu/i', $cmp);

 // $matches will be an associate array contains the matches
 // and $matches and $src are using same index key
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few approaches here, basically you could look at your current function: preg_match. By the way i don't think you can put a array into the subject parameter if it requires a string. For now i will guess you are putting a string there with the wrong name.

You could use it also to save the matches found like so:

```
$check = preg_match($regex, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

If it is an array you should approach it like a single result and loop trough it (there are betters ways, but this is an approach you are using and i try to teach you this better.

```
// Your code ....

foreach($anArray as $rule) {
  $check = preg_match($regex, $anArray, $matches);
  if($check == 1) {
    echo print_r($matches);
  }
}
```